# How does one select all columns but rename some of them in one statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Normally I would write a statement like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table;
```

But I have two columns, (both of date type), called 'created' and 'edited'. If I do select *, then the date in each of these columns will appear as:

```
2017-11-04T18:30:00.000Z
```

I would rather the date appear in DD/MON/YYYY.

To do that, I currently modify my SQL statement to:

```
SELECT column_name1,column_name2,column_name3,to_char(created, 'DD-MON-YYYY') as created,column_name4.... FROM my_table;
```

The problem is that although I can format the date, I have the problem of having to specify each column name in the statement. Is there some way I can select all the columns (but rename one or more columns using the method above), without having to specify each column name ?

Comment: The display of the columns is done by the SQL client you are using. The easiest way is to just configure that SQL tool to format timestamp columns differently

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select to_char(t.created,'DD-MON-YYYY') as created,to_char(t.edited,'DD-MON-YYYY') as edited, t.* from my_table t;
```